# Remove dashed border for Vaadin 14 readonly textfields

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow

A read-only TextField has a dashed border in Vaadin 14, like this one:

[image: Vaadin 14 TextField readonly with dashed border]

I want to remove the dashed border. For some TextFields (ideally only those with a special CSS classname - but I guess that the extension of the CSS selector is no problem later).

Therefore I created a file textfieldstyles.css in [projekt]/frontend/styles/ with this content:

```
[part="input-field"]::after {
border-style: none;
border-width: 0px;
border-color: white;
/* does not change anything: border: 0px none white; */
}
```

and added an annotation at my Vaadin-Java-component:

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/textfieldstyles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field")
```

This does not (fully) work as expected: my CSS code is part of the element's style (yeah, success :) ), but only AFTER the dashing style (oh no :( ). The result is still a dashed border.
Here is a screenshot of Firefox inspector:

[image: my CSS is inserted after the generated]

How can I rank my styles higher than the standard Vaadin styles?

Comment: You can use `!important`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Yes, the effect with "border-color: transparent !important;" is as desired. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (and the solution) was already in my question: "[...] I guess that the extension of the CSS selector is no problem later [...]".

Everything works fine when I use a more specialized CSS selector in [project]/frontend/styles/textfieldstyles.css:

```
:host(.my-special-classname) [part="input-field"]::after {
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: white;
}
```

The TextField of course has to get that class name:

```
textField.addClassName("my-special-classname");
```

Then Firefox shows the order I wanted to have and the Vaadin 14 readonly TextField has no dashed border any more:

[image: Vaadin 14 readonly TextField without dashed border]

Comment: Keep in mind that with this solution, the placement of the textfield will be around 1-2 pixels off because it no longer has a border width. This might maybe not be noticed in your case, but in some cases this could break the whole layout. When going with the solution of making the border transparent, this issue will no longer exist.

Comment: Interesting hint. Thank you for that! Indeed it has no effect in my case no matter if the border width is 0, 1 or even 10: The content is always placed the same and all neighbours also are in the same position as in the other cases. Testet with the target browsers FireFox (73.0.1) and Chromium (80.0.3987.122).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to accomplish what you want; most involve `!important`, like:

```
border-color: transparent !important;
```

It's easy to abuse `!important` to brute-force styles you want, but in this case, seems like an appropriate use.  Btw you could also override other `border-*` CSS attributes, but just one will do it, as in my example above. Also, avoiding changing `border-width` means not changing layout at all; the button retains its dimensions (including border width) by just making the border invisible (`transparent`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, the effect with "border-color: transparent !important;" is as desired. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to doing something similar and found this ["official"](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-text-field/html-examples/text-field-styling-demos) way. You can add the following CSS in the index.html, which will change the border to a thin grey one instead of removing the dashed.

```
<dom-module id="read-only-field-styles" theme-for="vaadin-text-field">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host(.read-only) [part="input-field"]::after {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        border-color: grey;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Then, add the class name "read-only" to all your `vaadin-text-field`.

```
  <vaadin-text-field class="read-only" label="XXX" id="xxx" readonly></vaadin-text-field>
```