# Vaadin TextField readonly style

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

How can I change the style of a readonly TextField in Vaadin?

Now the default style after setting setReadOnly(true) is following:

[image]

I want this style with no border and an other backgroundcolor:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove dashed border for Vaadin 14 readonly textfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355258/remove-dashed-border-for-vaadin-14-readonly-textfields)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try with this code for that particular text field you want to modify:

```java
TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setReadOnly(true);

        // Remove border and set background color to gray
        textField.getElement().getStyle().set("border", "none");
        textField.getElement().getStyle().set("background-color", "gray");
```

it is worth noticing that if you want the whole application with that style please follow [the documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/text-field/styling).
in there you can find how to customize all the text fields in your application.